# linux screen -r doesn't work

Tags: linux, terminal, gnu-screen

I am trying to re-attach different screen sessions that I have open.  As usual, I try:

```
screen -r [screen name]
```

This normally works, but now it keeps hanging the terminal.  Ctrl+c doesn't help, and I end up having to close the terminal.  Other screen functions (`screen -ls`, `screen -S [new screen name]`) work fine.

One of the screens has a process running in it.  I can see from the existence of generated output files that the process is still running.  I just can't access the screen itself.

I tried creating a new screen, detaching it, and re-attaching it - this works fine.  I can access new screens, but not the ones that were open before this problem popped up.

Comment: Sounds like the process running in that session is blocking Ctl-c. Does `C-a w` work after you reattach to it?

Comment: If you accidentally pressed `ctrl-a`, `s` to pause it, you can undo it with `ctrl-a`, `q`

Comment: Thank you for the responses!  The issue is that I can't get the screen to reattach - so, I can't get to the point where I would run ctrl-a....

Answer (score 1):

You should do kill the screens which has problem. Try,

```
screen -X -S <screenname> kill
```

If it's not working, you should kill these processes by yourself. First you should find which are those have an issue. By typing;

```
ps aux
```

Then find PID number of process which you want to kill. And type;

```
kill -9 <pidnumber>
```

And check it works fine :)

Regards,

Evren